send_transaction rarely get confirmed
My transactions only rarely get confirmed, sometimes only once a day, even though I’m using a paid starter plan with QuickNode. Despite raising this issue with QuickNode, I haven’t received a response in two weeks. Could you please help explain why most of my transactions are being dropped? Here’s the code I’m currently using.
https://github.com/Allen-Taylor/moonshot_py/blob/main/moonshot_py/moonshot.py
-Thanks :)

If your are hitting accounts that are used a lot you may need to adjust your priority fees. It looks like you already have a pretty high value hardcoded though.
Maybe try the quicknode priority fee api:
https://marketplace.quicknode.com/add-on/solana-priority-fee
Or try another RPC provider and see if they give better results.
Also worth printing out the simulation result of your transaction to see why they fail or try disable preflight checks.

Hi Bro, The code works amazing with Solana's main net RPC: https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com. But since I paid for the Quick node, I was expecting great service!

Usually quicknode should work fine as well. Not sure whats going on

Consider Chainstack Growth plan with a discount on the first month. Within this plan you can test Solana Trader nodes to achieve the fastest landing of transactions.
P.S. I'm a Developer Advocate at Chainstack.
